# Automatically ssh into remote host depending on the folder you're in

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there a solution (or plugin for zsh) that will allow me to remote ssh depending on the folder in local OS? Similar to PyENV.

So if I develop a project and do

```
cd /home/projects/ERP
ssh production
ssh development
```

so that with easy to remember commands I jump right into desired remote host?

I understand I can do aliases and load them from a local folder when I switch dirs, but is there a better way?

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment to ask for clarification, so I'll just guess here, and edit my answer as necessary if it's incomplete.

I don't know of any such plugin, but writing one would not be too difficult. Your use case is not a common one, so that's probably the way to go. There are like 5 different ways to do this.

First, though, I should mention that it is entirely possible to have "host aliases" in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`, which makes it easy to assign a specific host alias to a set of configuration options for SSH.

Below is an example.

```
Host router
    Hostname 10.0.0.1
    Port 222
    User root
```

This would make typing `ssh router` equivalent to typing `ssh root@10.0.0.1 -p 222`.

This probably covers a significant amount of your use case. Sorry if you already knew this -- I'm just trying to cover all the bases, here.

If you really need SSH to interpret a fixed SSH command in different ways, you would most likely need a wrapper around the SSH command which looks at the input arguments, recognizes key ones (e.g., production or development), interprets those, then picks one of the possible hosts (possibly pre-configured in the SSH config) depending on the value of `$PWD`.

Let me know if this helps! ^.^

---

Update: thanks a bunch to @fra-san, who pointed out a *much* more elegant option! :D (At the very least, much more elegant if you have relatively few special cases...)

You can simply do:

```
Match host production, exec ssh_match_dir
    Port 5555
    Hostname foodev.biz
```

Where `ssh_match_dir` is a script in your PATH that exits with status 0 when it detects that the condition should apply, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if test "$PWD" = "/home/a/git"; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Be sure to look at `man ssh_config` and pay especial attention to the `TOKENS` section -- which includes info on arguments you can tell `ssh` to pass to the script to add extra conditions. I believe you could have a single script handle each host with different arbitrary conditions if you use `exec ssh_match_dir %h` and add some argument parsing to the script -- depending on what your use case is.

Comment: You might add a mention to the `Match` directive, that can be used in `ssh_config` or `config` to apply subsequent directives according to the result of a test. E.g. the line `Match host project, exec test_for_current_dir` will apply subsequent directives only if we are connecting to `project` and `test_for_current_dir` returns 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @fra-san! I've updated my answer. :)